# Text truncated on JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a *JasperReports*'s report within an application that is truncating text and I am unsure how to get it to display the full name.

The code snippet below shows that I have included `isStretchWithOverflow="true"`:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="353" y="0" width="79" height="30"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{acname}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The JasperReports's image shows incorrect values. One of these should read: 'Double Time Pay - Bill Regular' and the other 'Double Time Pay - Bill Overtime'.

[image: Jasper Report]

Comment: 'acname' from the code snipped = 'Pay Class' in the report.

Comment: Strange, since the following words "Regular" and "Overtime" are not that long. It should show up Where is this textField located? Details band? Is the textfield on the right side outside of the report? A bit more source code might help.

Comment: @BrettKnell It is a uncomfortably to work with image instead of text (snippet of code)

Comment: Ok apologies: `<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement x="353" y="0" width="79" height="30"/>
     <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{acname}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>`

Comment: @Brett, this code is not reproducible for us (I have tried your text in a small field), show exactly what "$F{acname}" contains, put it in a long text field with no textAlignment, do you get same result?

Comment: This is what I tried `<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="79" height="30" uuid="6366aa58-1978-4d80-bb6f-ed2a48011530"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Double Time Pay - Bill Overtime"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>` and it worked without problems

Comment: Petter, thank you, that works great